# Splitting string with Regex with exceptions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

Been trying to split a string by [space] but with some exceptions in javascript, but only with partial success.

String:

```
Surname, Name (description) Category1 Surename, Name Category2 "Category3" " Cate gory4",    category5 (category1)
```

Wanted output:

```
- Surname, Name (description)
- Category1
- Surename, Name 
- Category2
- "Category3"
- " Cate gory4"
- category5 (category1)
```

Tried regex

```
\s+(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)(?=[^()]*(?:\(|$))(?=[^(])
```

Provisional output

```
- Surname, 
- Name (description) 
- Category1 
- Category2 
- "Category3" 
- " Cate gory4", 
- category5 (category1)
```

I cant find a way to make the exception for ", ".

Anyone who have an idea for solving this?

**EDIT:** Added an alternative string in string and output.

Best regards
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex based on alternation:

```js
var str = 'Surname, Name (description) Category1 Surename, Name Category2 "Category3" " Cate gory4",    category5 (category1)';

var m = str.match(/\b\w+ *, *\w+\b(?!\s*\()|\b\w[\w,\s]*\([^)]+\)|"[^"]*"|\b\S+/g);

console.log(m);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QxKQUA/12)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\b\w+ *, *\w+\b(?!\s*\()` - Match comma separated names not followed by `(...)`
- `\b\w[\w,\s]*\([^)]+\)` - Match some text followed by `(...)` OR
- `"[^"]*"` - Match quoted string
- `\b\S+` - Match 1 or more non-space text

**Output:**

```
[
  "Surname, Name (description)",
  "Category1",
  "Surename, Name",
  "Category2",
  "\"Category3\"",
  "\" Cate gory4\"",
  "category5 (category1)"
]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, I accepted the answer becous It did result in excactly the way I wished it to. Theres only one catch, If a Name is seperated with comma, without a following paranteses, it still split on the space. Any Idea of how to solve this? Regex is really not my strongest ability.

Comment: Sure: [
  "Surname, Name (description)",
  "Category7",
  "Surname, Name",
  "Category1",
  "Category2",
  "\"Category3\"",
  "\" Cate gory4\"",
  "category5 (category1)"
]  from this var str = 'Surname, Name Category7 Surname, Name (description) Category1 Category2 "Category3" " Cate gory4",    category5 (category1)';  Thanx :-)

Comment: Hi, Added it now. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Hi again @anubhava, did you have a chance to check the regex. I've been trying alot now, and are pretty close to give it up

Comment: Sorry I missed your earlier comment. Let me take a look at it now.

Comment: thats just amazing

Comment: Thank you! I'm impressed